# Loop over files and clean RTF tags with RegEx in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a lot of text files (one per day 2018-2022) in a directory. These contain text formatted with RTF tags that I want to get rid of. I can do this in Qlikview/Qlik Sense which is my area of expertise using replace and mapping functions. The problem is that its very time consuming and I hope cleaning these files first using a regular expression would speed up the process a lot.

I've never programmed anything in PowerShell so I have problems putting it all together.

I tried this string

```
\{\*?\\[^{}]+}|[{}]|\\\n?[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?|(\\\[0-9a-f]+)[ ]?
```

in http://regexstorm.net/tester and it does what I want it to do.

How do I put it in a loop?
This is what I have so far:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem T:\somedirectory\TXT\SomeFile_*.txt)

using namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions
$regex = [Regex]::new('\{\*?\\[^{}]+}|[{}]|\\\n?[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?|(\\\[0-9a-f]+)[ ]?', [RegexOptions]::MultiLine)

foreach ($f in $files) {
$outfile = $f.FullName + "clean"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: not related to your question but your `using namespace` statement must be at the top of your script

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to do? Replace the matched content in the files with something else? Or just remove it completely?

Comment: Mathias:I’d like to remove the format tags or replace them with a blank space. 

Santiago: Thanks, will correct.